# Make an online application to open txt file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, readable

This is far fetched, but I know it can and has been done. Do you know how to make an online website/app to open a file? Basicly a website or an app that can read and output a HTML/TXT file. Preferably, I would like to use javascript or jquery, but any language that works on a website will be fine, too. There are online apps like [`Text for Chrome`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text/mmfbcljfglbokpmkimbfghdkjmjhdgbg?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-search) that do it. Do you know how? It would be great if you could help me out here. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Can describe _"open a file"_ ? Read user uploaded file ?

Comment: Yeah, like that. For example, a user uploads a file to the website, the website/app reads the file and puts the file back out on to the screen.

Comment: See post. Utilizes `input` , `textarea` elements ; `onchange` event ; `FileReader`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try utilizing `<input>` element ; `<textarea>` element ; `accept="text/plain"` attribute at `input` element ; `onchange` event attached to `input` element ; `FileReader()` within `onchange` event to output uploaded text file to `<textarea>` element

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var output = document.querySelector("[for=input]");
input.onchange = function(e) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(evt) {
    output.textContent = evt.target.result;
  };
  reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]);
};
```

```html
<input id="input" type="file" accept="text/plain" /><br />
<textarea for="input" style="width:300px;height:300px;"></textarea>
```